# Monitor application network traffic

Tags: networking, wireshark

I have application that connects to MQTT server and performs some actions. Is it possible somehow monitor network traffic that my application performs? I like Wireshark, but I can't find any feature that allows filtering by application.

Comment: You can use netsh to create a trace.  The resultant etl file can be opened with a tool such as Microsoft Network Monitor.  Another option might be Winshark but I've not really used it.  If you know the traffic of interest is coming from the WinHTTP library, then you can trace that library. https://troubleshooter879859767.wordpress.com/2020/12/21/etlprovidertrace/ might give you some ideas as well

Comment: @HelpingHand Winshark => Wireshark

Comment: @HelpingHand Microsoft Network Monitor has been deprecated and was replaced by Microsoft Message Analyzer which was discontinued in 2019. Wireshark is a better choice imo.

Comment: Some what sadly, Network Monitor is still the main UI tool for ETL traces. I had high hopes of Message Analyzer. Shame they killed it.

Comment: @HelpingHand You can convert the .etl file to a .pcapng file that you can open with Wireshark using https://github.com/microsoft/etl2pcapng